# onActivityResult not getting hit Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a piece of code that i am starting with startActivityForResult but the onActivityResult method is not getting hit, I have put in Log.d comments so I know whether or not the code is being hit here is my code:

```
  public class myClass extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.store_selector);
    Button getStore = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getStore);

    getStore.setOnClickListener(buttonGetStoreOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonGetStoreOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {


    Intent intent = new Intent("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.setPackage("com.blah.Blah");
    intent.putExtra("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    Log.d("debug tag", "started activity");
};
};  


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
   Log.d("debug tag", "inside onActivityResult");
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("debug tag", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Ads.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("key", contents);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ads);

            // Handle successful scan
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
    }
}


};
```

Comment: Are you setting resultCode in the other activity. Can you share your other activity where you are setting up your finish() intent.

Comment: Also, did you have a look at the tutorial for using Xzing on Android? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Are you certain that the activity you are trying to start when calling `startActivity()` actually gets run at all?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call  setResult() before calling finish() in the "com.blah.Blah" activity